# Find out which branch has the most recent version of a certain file

Tags: git

Say I have a file in a repo and I want to find out which branch has the most recent version of the file, let's say the filepath is 'foo'.

Let's assume the status/index/worktree of the repo is clean.

How can I go through all the branches local and remote and find out which commit on which branch holds the most recent change to 'foo'?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a recent enough version of git to support all this functionality:

- Get the commit ID of the last (reachable) commit to touch a file using

  ```
  git log --all --format=format:%H -n 1 -- path/to/file
  ```

  Here `--all` means to search the history of all refs (branches, tags, etc.), `--format=format:%H` means show only the commit ID, and `-n 1` means display only the first commit found. `git log` orders commits from newest to oldest, by default, so the first one will be the latest.
- Then find all branches which contain that commit using

  ```
  git branch --all --contains commitID
  ```

  You can omit `--all` if you want to see only local branches.

To combine these into one command that lists the branch names, assuming there is a commit that modifies the specified file:

```
git branch --all --contains "$(git log --all --format=format:%H -n 1 -- path/to/file)"
```

This procedure does not require the index and working tree to be clean, although it will only detect changes to the file that have been committed.

Comment: I just want local branches, so it should be `git branch` instead of `git branch --all` methinks

Comment: Yeah, true. My answer is based on what the question says, "...go through all the branches local and remote...."

Comment: So it's possible that more than one branch has that commit id, how do pick the first result from the --contains command? I guess it would be `git branch --contains ... | head -n 1`

Comment: Sure, if you just want one of them, that would work. I think they're listed in lexicographic order so you would get the first one from that ordering. If you want to choose which branch you get based on some other criteria, there are some options to `git branch` which you can use to limit the set of branches shown.

Answer (score 1):

The "source" flag to git-log adds the ref name.  When I tried, it shows the branch name, so you don't need the second step.  For example,

```
git log --all --source -n 1 -- pathname
```